# PHP preg_match ignore within certain elements

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm writing a `regex` where I need to filter content to format it's typography.  So far, my code seems to be filtering out my content properly using `preg_replace`, but I can't figure out how to avoid this for content wrapped within certain tags, say `<pre>`.

As a reference, this is to be used within WordPress's `the_content` filter, so my current code looks like so:

```
function my_typography( $str ) {
    $ignore_elements = array("code", "pre");

    $rules = array(
        "?" => array("before"=> "&thinsp;", "after"=>""),
        // the others are stripped out for simplicity
    );

    foreach($rules as $rule=>$params) {
        // Pseudo :
        //    if( !in_array( $parent_tag, $ignore_elements) {
        // /Pseudo


        $formatted = $params['before'] . $rule . $params['after'];
        $str = preg_replace( $rule, $formatted, $str );


        // Pseudo :
        //    }
        // /Pseudo
    }

    return $str;
}
add_filter( 'the_content',  'my_typography' );
```

Basically:

```
<p>Was this filtered? I hope so</p>
<pre>Was this filtered? I hope not.</pre>
```

should become

```
<p>Was this filtered&thinsp;? I hope so</p>
<pre>Was this filtered? I hope not.</pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap search regex with regex delimiter in `preg_replace` and must call `preg_quote` to escape all special regex characters such `?`, `.`, `*`, `+` etc:

```
$str = preg_replace( '~' . preg_quote($rule, '~') . '~', $formatted, $str );
```

**Full Code:**

```
function my_typography( $str ) {
    $ignore_elements = array("code", "pre");

    $rules = array(
        "?" => array("before"=> "&thinsp;", "after"=>""),
        // the others are stripped out for simplicity
    );

    foreach($rules as $rule=>$params) {
        // Pseudo :
        //    if( !in_array( $parent_tag, $ignore_elements) {
        // /Pseudo


        $formatted = $params['before'] . $rule . $params['after'];
        $str = preg_replace( '~' . preg_quote($rule, '~') . '~', $formatted, $str );


        // Pseudo :
        //    }
        // /Pseudo
    }

    return $str;
}
```

**Output:**

```
<p>Was this filtered&thinsp;? I hope so</p>
<pre>Was this filtered&thinsp;? I hope not.</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This does in fact manage the rules properly; however, my HTML is "broken" in the sense that in the expected output, `</p>` is returned as `< / p >` which breaks my page. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Your sample data doesn't have `</a>` anywhere but this code is just replacing `?` with something. Can you update the question that recreates this problem?

Comment: turns out my breaking HTML was one of the rules, had a rule for "/" -- sorry about that! here'S the checkmark, thanks for your time !